# Yii CListview ajax - displaying number of records next to checkbox used to filter data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox, yii

As the title says, i want to display the number of records next to the checkbox i am using to filter clistview data. This can be easily handled on page load, **however when doing an AJAX request, the $.fn.yiiListView.update code updates just the list data and due to the auto magic, I need some insight over how to perform operations such as update the number adjacent to each checkbox or disable a checkbox corresponding to suitable data.**

I really love the power given by CListView and wan't to stick to it as much as possible, hoping for quick resolution to this.

Comment: For quick resolution you need to post: 1st what you tried and what you did; 2nd formulate problem more specifically; 3rd show us your code, cause we are not telepaths.

Comment: The question was generic in terms of the way the CListView module's filter is supposed to function on an ajax update - would have surely provided data if needed - got the solution now though, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better look at the CListView module got me the answer.

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
          'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
          'itemView'=>'_view',
          'sortableAttributes'=>array(
              'id'=>'cronologico',
              'transaction'
          ),
          'id'=>'ajaxListView',
          'ajaxUrl'=> $this->createUrl('/experience/ajaxindex'),
          'ajaxUpdate' => 'ratingFilter',
        )); 

        ?>
```

The key was the ajaxUpdate property that takes in id's of the tags to be updated along with the list. Multiple id's can be specified by comma separating them as part of the value.

Yii!